# Magento2 : Getting so many error js error

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

Getting so many js errors. Please help me how can I fix it. I did a lot search and tried given the solution. The site is in developer mode.

```
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/mage-init
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/keyboard
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/optgroup
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/after-render
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
makeError @ require.js:166
onScriptError @ require.js:1681
jquery.js:248 Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on tabs prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'option'
    at Function.error (https://garagedoors4lessstore.com/pub/static/version1501755728/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/en_US/jquery.js:248:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://garagedoors4lessstore.com/pub/static/version1501755728/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:488:15)
    at Function.each (https://example.com/pub/static/version1501755728/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/en_US/jquery.js:384:23)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (https://example.com/pub/static/version1501755728/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/en_US/jquery.js:137:17)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.(anonymous function) [as tabs] (https://example.com/pub/static/version1501755728/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui.js:484:9)
```

UPDATE : GETTING sIMILAR ERROR IN ADMIN  -----

```
admin-icons.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
opensans-600.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
opensans-400.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
opensans-700.woff2 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
magento-icon.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
jquery.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
require.js:141 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
```

- **I WAS ADD SSL TODAY**

Comment: Did u manage to fix the issue?

Comment: I am also facing same issue in admin due to which I am not able to login to admin.
can anyone please help.

Answer (score 4):

This problem on windows.

```
vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator
```

Fix function isPathInDirectories

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Answer (score 2):

Run both commands.

1. First

   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
2. Second

   `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Still getting similar error screenshot is attached.   http://prntscr.com/g3uxfz

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You include scripts without using **Require.js**. See [Magento DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs_concept.html). And your fonts haven't variant with ***.woff2**.